# Button with 2 colors and an image

Tags: html, css

So I’m trying to create a button with an small logo image with a darker background with a text with a lighter background. I managed to create just that but there is a problem when I use different texts with different lengths.

The problem I have is that the text isn't aligning in the centre because of the padding. But without the padding the text slides behind the image. Can someone help me out?

```css
.is-button {
  background-color: #1ea3ce;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  width: 85%;
  font-size: small;
  line-height: 20px;
  min-height: 80px;
  padding: 1% 2% 1% 20%;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.is-button:hover {
  filter: brightness(85%);
  color: #ffffff !important;
  -webkit-animation: none;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.01);
  animation: none;
  transform: scale(1.01);
}

.is-button .logo-button {
  background-color: #1b88b3;
  border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
  display: inline;
  height: inherit;
  padding: 4% 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align: center;">
  <a class="is-button" href="#"><img class="logo-button aligncenter" src="https://www.securityacademy.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/seco-logo-klein.png" />Information Security Foundation</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Please, provide a schematic image of what you're going to achieve, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `flex-box` css property and making your html syntax more correct is really simple to create what you want that is responsive:

```css
.is-button {
    background-color: #1ea3ce;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 100%;
    width: 85%;
    font-size: small;
    min-height: 80px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center; 
}

.is-button:hover {
    filter: brightness(85%);
    color: #ffffff !important;
}

.is-button .logo-button {
    background-color: #1b88b3;
    border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
    padding: 4% 5px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.is-button span {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10%;
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align: center;">
  <a class="is-button" href="#">
    <img class="logo-button aligncenter" src="https://www.securityacademy.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/seco-logo-klein.png" />
    <span>Information Security Foundation</span>
  </a>
</p>
```

Checkout the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaz1brh3/8/).

Comment: No problem ;) Remember to upvote a response that you consider as helpfull thanks

Comment: One more question, when I use your solution with differnt logo's the image isn't alligning to the left side of the button. Do you have a fix for that? see screenshot: https://www.securityacademy.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/button-logo.png

Comment: @gvankuijk are you sure that you have well implemented all the `css` ? I have tried again using another logo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6c4w1bL7/5/) and it's seems to work. Are you sure that your element `.is-button span` has the css property `width: 100%` ?

Comment: You are right, The width was on 85%.

One more question, when there is just one line of text in the button, the text won't align in the center. Seen screenshot: https://www.securityacademy.nl/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/sceenshot-9-1.png

Comment: @gvankuijk I updated the post. See the new css for `.is-button span` and `.is-button .logo-button`. I just add a `width: 100%` to the span element

Comment: Thanks a lot, the width and padding on the span did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Use css pseudo class `:before`

```css
.is-button:before {
  background-image:url('https://www.securityacademy.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/seco-logo-klein.png');
  background-size: 80px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  content:"";
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  background-color: #1ea3ce;
  border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
}
.is-button {
  background-color: #1ea3ce;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 85%;
  font-size: small;
  line-height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top:35px;
  padding-bottom:35px;
  padding-left:90px;
}

.is-button:hover {
  filter: brightness(85%);
  color: #ffffff !important;
  -webkit-animation: none;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.01);
  animation: none;
  transform: scale(1.01);
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align: center;">
  <a class="is-button" href="#">Information Security Foundation</a>
</p>
```